# Splitter contact: is payable modifier missing?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, console, modifiers, payable

I am using the geth javascript console, trying to split pre-fork ETH using the ReplaySafeSplit v2 contract `0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477` (code [here](https://etherscan.io/address/0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477#code)).

I am doing this as follows:

```
splitteraddr = "0xaBbb6bEbFA05aA13e908EaA492Bd7a8343760477"
abi = [{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"targetFork","type":"address"},{"name":"targetNoFork","type":"address"}],"name":"split","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"type":"function"}]
splitter = eth.contract(abi).at(splitteraddr)

preforkaddr = eth.accounts[0]
newethaddr = eth.accounts[1]
etcaddr = <a classic ether wallet address>

personal.unlockAccount(preforkaddr)
splitter.split.sendTransaction(newethaddr, etcaddr, {from: preforkaddr, value: web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'), gas: 100000, gasPrice: web3.toWei(100, 'gwei')})
```

However, this results in: `Error: Cannot send value to non-payable function`.

From what I understand so far, since v0.4.0 of solidity, functions need to be explicitly modified using `payable` (stated [here](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function)). The ReplaySafeSplit contract appears to have been compiled using v0.3.5 and the `split` function does not include this modifier.

Does this prevent my transaction from taking place through some mechanism built into geth? I can see by looking at the contract's transaction history that regular transactions are taking place so the contract is clearly usable.

Is there a workaround in geth? Am I getting something wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the deploy of [EIP 155](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/155), the replay protection is no longer needed.

But if you really need it you can modify the contract ABI adding `"payable":true` before `"type":"function"`. I didn't test this myself so you should try with a small amount first.

Comment: Thanks. I had eventually concluded that protection is no longer needed after coming across EIP155. There are still plenty of transactions running through it though. I also wondered about using a modified ABI (although didn't try it). But I wondered whether deviating from the "official" ABI would (a) work at all, or (b) lead to unexpected problems?